# How to convert pandas dataframe to matrix?

Tags: python, dataframe, matrix, converters

I want to convert `pandas dataframe` to a matrix in order to do some calculation, for example, column mean and row mean. After convert to the matrix, it still gives a nice looking column and row. In R, I can use `as.matrix(Chicago)` and this will give me a nice matrix as below:
[image]

However, when I use `np.asmatrix(chicago)` in python, it gives me:

[image]

May I know is it possible for python to get an nice output like R which also allow me to do row mean or column mean. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try `chicago.to_numpy()`. It should do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing calculations in the dataframe itself - using the `pandas.mean()` function.

Have a look at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html).

If you want to get the mean for each row, use: `chicago['mean'] = chicago.mean(axis=0)`

If you want to get the mean for each row, use: `chicago_column_mean = chicago.mean(axis=1)`

Comment: `Chicago` is one of my dataframe and I have another three different data frame from Houston, NewYork and SanFrancisco. If I do the calculation in data frame itself, is it possible to do the calculation all together without using `for loop` for the others three cities? Something like `apply` function in `R`.

Comment: Absolutely! I'd suggest doing the calculation on a combined dataframe that contains all the data. To do this, you combine all of the files together (assuming that the data is all the same).

1. move the Chicago data to a new dataframe called `df`
2. add a city column df['city'] = 'Chicago'
3. load another city (eg NewYork), set its city: newyork['city'] = 'New York'
4. append that newyork dataframe to df using: df = df.append(newyork)

I would recommend using a for loop to read all the data in and append it to a single dataframe if you have enough RAM, then do all the calculations.